# R can not add items in list in function in

Tags: r, list, function

I have following code

```
l=list()
funcF=function(x)
{
  l[[x]] ="somevalue"
}

funcF("A")
funcF("B")
print(l)
```

I was expecting

```
print(l)
```

to print

```
$A
[1] "somevalue"


$B
[1] "somevalue"
```

but it prints

```
"list()"
```

Why the list is empty, if I set the same values outside of the function it works.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A function is a closed system. The objects inside the function do not "know" that there is a list `l` on the outside.

If you want to manipulate an object such as the list `l`, you have to pass it to that function. Otherwise it is beyond the scope of the function and inaccessible to it.

See what happens if I re-write the function like this:

```
l=list()
funcF=function(x,y,z)
{
  x[[y]] = z
  return(x)
}

funcF(l,"A","someA")

#> funcF(l,"A","someA")
#$A
#[1] "someA"

funcF(l,"B","someB")

#> funcF(l,"B","someB")
#$B
#[1] "someB"

l <- funcF(l,"A","someA")
l <- funcF(l,"B","someB")
l

#> l
#$A
#[1] "someA"
#
#$B
#[1] "someB"
```

In the newly written function `x` is the target list, `y` denotes the "slot" to be filled, and `z` is the value that is assigned to the slot.

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks @SimonG ... this explains it. My function need to return some other value as well, are there out parameters in R?